# Entity Framework Code First Reverse Engineer - Use specific schema?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, ef-code-first, reverse-engineering

When using the EF(6.1.3) Code First Reverse Engineering toolset, I note that even though under Filters I select BOTH default and the schema I want, the tool is only generating POCOs for the default schema.

This is to an Oracle 11g db, using ODP.NET 12c (ManagedDataAccess) and ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, if it matters...

Comment: Share your code please ?

Comment: There is no code involved?  Right click on the project, select Entity Framework, select Reverse Engineer Code First, dialog box opens, Click Change for Data Source, select Oracle Database / ODP.NET Managed from the dropdown, input username and password, as well as connection type, click on Filters, Add second schema, click update, click OK, and note that only the tables from the primary login schema is created.

Comment: check this please https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj593170.aspx